# Не работает клиент-сервер на Android

Tags: java, android

Есть стандартный алгоритм клиент-сервера.

Сервер:

```
//класс в новом потоке
class ServeOneThread extends Thread {

long n;
String HostName;
Socket socket;
BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;

public ServeOneThread(Socket s, String HostName, long n) throws IOException {
    this.n = n; //эта переменная получает по параметру № климента, который подключился
    this.HostName = HostName;  //эта переменная получает по параметру имя климента, который подключился
    this.socket = s;
    //в этупеременную будутт поступать данные
    this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    //эта переменная на вывод данных клиенту
    this.out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
    start();
}


public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            String str = in.readLine();
            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
                    break;
            }
            int a=1+3; //разного рода вычесление
            out.println("Я получил Ваши данные, вот то что Вы прислали: "+str);
            out.println("Я выполнилась операцию: "+a);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Соединение № "+ n +". Ошибка при передачи клиенту: " +HostName);
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Соединение № "+ n +". Не получается разорвать связь с клиентом: " +HostName);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Завершено соединение № "+ n +", клиент: " +HostName+" отключен");

}
}


public class Server {

static final int PORT = 8888;
static String HostName = null;
static long n = 0;
static ServerSocket s;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try{
        s = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Порт: "+PORT+" занят");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Запуск сервера АРЕНА");
    System.out.println("Ожидаю клиентов....");
    try {
        //мониторю порт
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = s.accept();  //подключаю клиент
            HostName=socket.getInetAddress().getHostName(); //получаю в переменную имя клиента
            n++;
            System.out.println("Соединение № "+ n +". Подключился клиент: "+HostName);
            try {
                new ServeOneThread(socket, HostName, n);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Соединение № "+ n +" с клиентом: "+HostName+" разорвано");
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        s.close();
        System.out.println("Соединение с портом разорвано разорвано");

    }
}
}
```

Клиент на ПК:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Client side");

        //обьявляю переменные
        Socket fromserver = null;
        int port = 8888;
        String address = "127.0.0.1";

        try {
            System.out.println("Подключение к " + address+":"+port+"...");
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); // создаем объект который отображает вышеописанный IP-адрес.
            fromserver = new Socket(ipAddress,port); // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
            System.out.println("Подключение успешное, вводите сообщения");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Не удалось подключится к " + address+":"+port);
            System.exit(-1); //если нет такого порта - выход с программы
        }


        BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromserver.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter    out = new PrintWriter(fromserver.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader inu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String fuser,fserver;

        while ((fuser = inu.readLine())!=null) {
            out.println(fuser);
            fserver = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(fserver);
            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) break;
            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        inu.close();
        fromserver.close();
    }
}
```

И клиент на андроиде:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Socket client = null;
int port = 8888;
String address = "192.168.1.25";
String coment=null;
TextView com;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    com=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCom);
    Button btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

public void onClick(View v) {
    // по id определеяем кнопку, вызвавшую этот обработчик
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSend:
            Conect();
            com.setText(coment);
            break;
    }
}

void Conect(){
    //открываю новый поток
    Thread myThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {
        @Override
        //то что должно запускаться в новом потоке
        public void run() {
            try {
                // создаем объект который отображает вышеописанный IP-адрес.
                InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
                // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
                client = new Socket(ipAddress,port);
                //переменная для получение данных
                BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                //переменная для отправки данных
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                coment=("Успешное подключение к " + address+":"+port+"...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                coment=("Не удалось подключится к " + address+":"+port);
            }
        }
    });
    myThread.start(); //запуск нового потока
}

}
```

Есть 3 устройства: 2 ноутбука и 1 смартфон на андроиде. Все связаны локальной сетью через Wi-Fi. Запускаю сервер на 192.168.1.25 ноуте. Запускаю клиент или много клиентов на втором ноуте. Все прекрасно работает, есть конект, сервер отдает в ответ инфу. Но а когда запускаю клиент на андроиде, то сервет никак не реагирует (он должен написать, что к нему присоединен еще один клиент), а андроид-клиент выдает ошибку, что не может соединится. Что я делаю не так, ведь я же запускаю сокет в отдельном потоке??? Спасибо за ранее за ответы и помощь.

Comment: А какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: coment=("Не удалось подключится к " + address+":"+port);

Comment: Нам бы собственно ошибку знать, коя выводится >e.printStackTrace();

Comment: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: coment=("Не удалось подключится к " + address+":"+port+" ошибка номер №: "+e);  это то что мне выдало в переменной е

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [гуглу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11273223/3212712) сия ошибка вызвана отсутствием разрешения на интернет в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, теперь и я понял как ошибки искать