# Подключение по TCP

Tags: java, tcp-ip

Привет. Я от сюда([Не работает клиент-сервер на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428646/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android)). У меня проблема при конекте по TCP между двумя компами. Ноуты подключены к одной сети wifi. Обращаюсь к ним по локальным ip-адресам в сети. Когда запускаю клиент и сервер на одном компе, то все работает. Фаервол отключен. Порты открыты. Не знаю в чем проблема.
Вот если что код клиента и сервера.

```
public class client {
public static void main(String[] ar) {
String address = ar[0]; //параметрами получаем адрес и порт
    int serverPort = Integer.parseInt(ar[1]); 


    try {
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); 
        System.out.println("Any of you heard of a socket with IP address " + address + " and port " + serverPort + "?"+ ipAddress);
        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort); 
        System.out.println("Yes! I just got hold of the program.");


        InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();


        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);


        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("Type in something and press enter. Will send it to the server and tell ya what it thinks.");
        System.out.println();

        while (true) {
            line = keyboard.readLine(); 
            System.out.println("Sending this line to the server...");
            out.writeUTF(line); 
            out.flush(); // заставляем поток закончить передачу данных.
            line = in.readUTF(); 
            System.out.println("The server was very polite. It sent me this : " + line);
            System.out.println("Looks like the server is pleased with us. Go ahead and enter more lines.");
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}

////////Сервер     
public class Server {
   public static void main(String[] ar){
     int port = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]); 
       try {
         ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port); 
         System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

         Socket socket = ss.accept(); 
         System.out.println("Got a client :) ... Finally, someone saw me through all the cover!");
         System.out.println();


         InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
         OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();


         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

         String line = null;
         while(true) {
           line = in.readUTF(); 
           System.out.println("The dumb client just sent me this line : " + line);
           System.out.println("I'm sending it back...");
           out.writeUTF(line); 
           out.flush(); 
           System.out.println("Waiting for the next line...");
           System.out.println();
         }
      } catch(Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй мой отредактированный вариант. Обрати внимание на передаваемые параметры - адрес и порт.

```
public class Client {
    static Socket socket;
    static DataInputStream in;
    static DataOutputStream out;

    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        String address = ar[0]; //параметрами получаем адрес и порт
        int serverPort = Integer.parseInt(ar[1]); 


        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); 
            System.out.println("Any of you heard of a socket with IP address " + address + " and port " + serverPort + "?"+ ipAddress);
            socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort); 
            System.out.println("Yes! I just got hold of the program.");


            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();


            in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            out = new DataOutputStream(sout);


            BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("Type in something and press enter. Will send it to the server and tell ya what it thinks.");
            System.out.println();

            while (true) {
                line = keyboard.readLine(); 
                System.out.println("Sending this line to the server...");
                out.writeUTF(line); 
                out.flush(); // заставляем поток закончить передачу данных.
                line = in.readUTF(); 
                System.out.println("The server was very polite. It sent me this : " + line);
                System.out.println("Looks like the server is pleased with us. Go ahead and enter more lines.");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                if(socket!=null) {
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Соединение с портом разорвано разорвано");

        }
    }
}

public class Server {

    static ServerSocket ss;

    public static void main(String[] ar){
        int port = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]); 

        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Порт: "+port+" занят");
            return;
        }


        try {

             System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

             while(true) {

                 Socket socket = ss.accept(); 
                 System.out.println("Got a client :) ... Finally, someone saw me through all the cover!");
                 System.out.println();


                 InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
                 OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();


                 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
                 DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

                 String line = null;

               line = in.readUTF(); 
               System.out.println("The dumb client just sent me this line : " + line);
               System.out.println("I'm sending it back...");
               out.writeUTF(line); 
               out.flush(); 
               System.out.println("Waiting for the next line...");
               System.out.println();
             }
        } catch(Exception x) { 
            x.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(ss!=null) {
                ss.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Соединение с портом разорвано разорвано");

        }
    }
}
```